# Refreshing json on an interval and displaying results without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JSON like what you see below, that I want to "keep alive".  I would like to continually query the server ("refresh" at a continual interval, say 30 seconds) and update what's displayed on the page accordingly.  The JSON appears as so:

```
[
        {
            "Name": "Paul",
            "Date": "2012-10-26",
            "Score": 8
        },
        {
            "Name": "Janet",
            "Date": "2012-10-24",
            "Score": 18
        },
        {
            "Name": "Rick",
            "Date": "2012-10-26",
            "Score": 13
        }
]
```

My current (static) version to display this is:

```
<body>
<script>
$.getJSON('myjson.json', function(data) {
for (var i in data) {
var Name = data[i].Name;
var Score = data[i].Score;
}           
var output = "<ul>";
for (var i in data) {
output += "<li>" + Name + "--" + Score;
}
output += "</ul>";
document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;
});
</script>
<div id="placeholder"></div>
</body>
```

This of course displays the data, but how would I "stream" the changes to "Score" as the json changes on the server (without refreshing the page)?

Is this what's referred to as polling?

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use a timer, or to be more specific, `setInterval()`...

```
<script>
    function getData() {
        $.getJSON('myjson.json', function(data) {
            for (var i in data) {
                var Name = data[i].Name;
                var Score = data[i].Score;
            }           
            var output = "<ul>";
            for (var i in data) {
                output += "<li>" + Name + "--" + Score;
            }
            output += "</ul>";
            document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;
        });
    }
    setInterval(getData, 30000);

    $(function() {
        getData();
    });
</script>
```

The above script will run the `getData()` function at document.ready and then every 30 seconds, and update the `#placeholder` element with the return value.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I noticed that on the first go, it waits the 30seconds before the data is first displayed.  How would I change it to load immediatly when the page loads, and then every 30seconds thereafter?

Comment: I'll amend to suit that :)

Answer (score 1):

Without any bells or whistles, you could just wrap that whole thing up in a function and then call it with a [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) or [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) so that it runs the code at the given interval.

Basic example:

```
function getData(){
  ... your code ...

  setTimeout( getData, 3000 ); // Get data and refresh page every 3000 ms (3 seconds)
}
```

// Call function to kick off data collection

```
getData();
```